# Connect a website to a postgresql database

Tags: web-mapping, pgadmin-3

I am using pgadmin 3 software for database. I would like to connect this database to my website so that I can retrieve ,add delete database entries from the website

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want a web console like pgadmin you could try something from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5726323/1504487). If you really want to include functionality in your website you will need to implement a server part with something like php (search for "postgresql php tutorial" or the likes).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to operate postgres database from a browser client, you must use server side script(s) which offers postgres API. There are several possible solutions, some of them:

- Node.js (javascript)
- Laravel (PHP)
- Django (Python)
- Python + Psycopg
- PHP & PDO

It is impossible to explain more details here.